# base href breaks addon loading - Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

When I use `<base href="/">` it breaks my bootstrap loadings. It also seems to break main.js for some reason. I found that doing `<base href="./">` makes it work again, but am unsure if this is safe or good practice. I should also note that my project is inside a folder from `/var/www/html`

Answer (score 1):

You can use instead

```
@NgModule({
  ...,
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'}],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Is this compatible with routing?

Comment: Yes, this is what the router uses. Either `<base ...>` or `APP_BASE_HREF`. `APP_BASE_HREF` overrides `<base ...>`. I think it was introduced exactly for your use case, because sometimes what the rest of the page needs differs from what the router needs.

Comment: I'll test it out and mark it as answer if it work for me tomorrow.

Comment: Hmm, it's not working as what i'm intending. So I have a subfolder (called hira) and it's giving me the error `Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'hira'` what yours is doing is basically trying to make my thing go to `www.website.com/routes` whereas I want to go to `www.website.com/hira/routes`

Comment: I added a `path: 'hira', redirectTo: 'search', pathMatch: 'full'` to my app-routing.module.ts but I was wondering if there was any relative way to do it. Say if I rename the folder from hira to hira2, so I don't have to go in and change it every time.

Comment: Don't think there is